# check values in for loop python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a multi language site for product i have images which has content in two languages 
english and spanish.

I need to differentiate them for the particular site, but I am getting all images in one for loop

```
 {% for image in images %}  {% endfor %}
```

in which the image names are like

```
 image.jpg  
 image_en.jpg   
 image_sp.jpg
```

For english site I need "image.jpg" and "image_en.jpg" and for spanish  I need "image.jpg" and "image_sp.jpg"

How can i differentiate them?

Comment: This isn't Python code. It seems like it's either Jinja2 or Django Templates? What is your exact question?

Comment: -1. First, that is clearly Django syntax, not Python. Secondly, you don't show how you're getting those image names in the first place.

Comment: Are you using internalization tags and filters? Did you thought about using them?

Comment: Best way for you is to show us the code that retrieves the images, then work something out from there to filter them based on the language code

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the lengauge on your server site. Then create a set of name (in case of english and spanish) then simple print this images in templates. This looks easy but maybe it's not the best.